# drawing a christmas tree

Tags: shell, for-loop, drawing

I'm trying to draw a tree in the following form

```
    *    
   ***
  *****
 *******
*********
```

as you can see I need both spaces, and "*" stars in every line, but I can't get it quite the way I want

```
#!/bin/bash

display_tree() {
    local rows=$1
    local columns=$2

    for ((i=0; i<$rows; i++))
    do
        #spaces loop
        for ((j=0; j<$columns; j++))
        do
            echo -n " "
            #drawing tree loop
            for ((a=0; a<$(($i + 1)); a++))
            do
                echo -n "*"
            done
        done
    echo 
    done
}

if [ $# -eq 2 ]; then
    display_tree $1 $2
else
    echo "Usage: $0 rows columns"
fi
```

Comment: It looks like you haven't formalized how many spaces you need to emit before you emit stars, and you have wrapped your inner loops instead of making them consecutive.  When the tree is 3 rows high, how many spaces do you need to put before the first star on row 1, row 2, and row 3?  How does your code ensure that happens? (Hint, it doesn't yet — so you'll have to modify it until it does.)

Comment: and you will understand better the internals of your script if you modify the innermost loop to emit `printf "a=%s\ti=%s\tj=%s\n" $a $i $j > "/dev/tty????"` where ???? is the result of running `tty` in a separate window and then substituting the number for '????' in my sample. OR you can leave out the `> "/dev/tty..."` and have the output intermingled with your Xmas tree. Good luck.

Answer (score 3):

This seems to work for me. Odd numbers recommended for the "columns" argument.  Looks prettiest when columns = 2*rows - 1.  The longest line in the code does some elementary algebra in play, specifically linear interpolation, used to figure the number of stars to display in a given row.

```
#!/bin/bash
# Christmas tree ASCII drawer
# works nicest for odd integers

spaces() {
  for ((i=0; i<$1; i++)) ; do
    echo -n " "
  done 
}

stars() {
  for ((i=0; i<$1; i++)) ; do
    echo -n "*"
  done
  echo ""
}

display_tree() {
    local rows=$1
    local columns=$2

    # render
    for (( r=1; r <= $rows; r++ )); do
      s=$(( (((columns-1) * (r-1)/(rows-1) + 1)/2)*2 +1 ))
      spaces $(((columns-s)/2))
      stars $s
    done
}

if [ $# -eq 2 ]; then
    display_tree $1 $2
else
    echo "Usage: $0 rows columns"
fi
```

Example output:

```
./display_tree.sh 5 21
          *
       *******
     ***********
  *****************
*********************

./display_tree.sh 30 59
                             *
                            ***
                           *****
                          *******
                         *********
                        ***********
                       *************
                      ***************
                     *****************
                    *******************
                   *********************
                  ***********************
                 *************************
                ***************************
               *****************************
              *******************************
             *********************************
            ***********************************
           *************************************
          ***************************************
         *****************************************
        *******************************************
       *********************************************
      ***********************************************
     *************************************************
    ***************************************************
   *****************************************************
  *******************************************************
 *********************************************************
***********************************************************
```

Answer (score 1):

The logic for this solution is quite simple, probably the best way to explain is to draw a few levels of a tree in a text editor and count the number of stars and spaces for each iteration. You quickly realize that it comes to generating a set of numbers. For example:

`3 1
2 3 
1 5
0 7`

All you have to do now is to set a starting point ($COLUMNS/2). 
The $(eval ...) part is just a trick to print spaces and stars without using 
a loop. Eval is needed because brace shell expansion {1..$var} does not work without it.

```
spaces=$(($COLUMNS/2)); 
for ((i=1; i < $LINES; i+=2)); 
    do echo "$(eval printf '\ %.0s' {1..$spaces}) $(eval printf '*%.0s' {1..$i})"; 
    ((spaces--));
done;
```

Comment: @Filnor I thought that the logic would be obvious but I guess I was wrong. I will provide an explanation of how the code works.

Answer (score 0):

```
letters=( \" \');while true;do clear; letter=${letters[$[RANDOM%${#letters[@]}]]}; [[ $letter == \" ]] && color=35 || color=32;m=2;i=77;p=$(($i/2-1)); while [[ $m -le $i ]];do printf "%${p}s" ;printf "\e[4;${color}m${letter}%.0s\e[m" $(seq $m);echo;m=$[m+2];((p--));done;sleep 1;done
```